# Jmeter non-gui execution stucks at report generation while heavy load test

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a test for an HTTP Sampler request for 30 mins with 50 threads as below Concurrency Thread Group config
[image]

While running over non-gui mode, the execution is getting stuck at **Tyding up**
[image]

I searched many things though unable to figure out why execution gets stuck there and below is what I've found in jmeter.log file
[image]

I am using ***Jmeter 5.3*** and ***Java 10*** with increased **heap size to 4g over AWS running with 8g RAM Xeon 2.5Ghz processor**

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I face similar issue with heavy load test, the input csv is 332MB size in my case. Could you find any solution . Does increasing heap size further help.